# do any one use Dr scheme programming? how to sort using list?

Tags: scheme, racket

which data structure to use to sort n numbers in dr scheme i m not allowed to use vector and structure ..if i use list i cant edit the list values .so how can i sort n numbers . the language i use is textual mzscheme rsr5

Answer (score 7):

If you cannot edit the list values ... return a new list! :-)

Answer (score 4):

The insertion sort solution is pretty easy in scheme (with BigO of N^2 performance it is poor but still does the job)

For sorting n numbers, you can use the list data type to hold the values and a list of numbers is either;

- empty,
- (cons number ListofNumber)

For insertion sort, you need 2 functions, and Inserter that does a single insert of a number to an already sorted list of numbers and another function that will call this insert recursivly.

The input-output of insert function

```
;;insert: Number ListOfNumber(Sorted) -> ListOfNumber(Sorted)
(define (insert n lon)
    (cond
        [(empty? lon) (cons n lon)] 
        [(<= n (first lon)) (cons n lon)] 
        (else 
            (cons (first lon) (insert n (rest lon))) )))


;;insertion-sort: ListOfNumber -> ListOfNumber(Sorted)
(define (insertion-sort lon)
    (cond
        [(empty? lon) lon] ;;if the list is empty than the numbers are sorted
        (else
            (insert (first lon) (insertion-sort (rest lon))) )))
```

I hope this answer fits your question

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are supposed to be writing your own bubblesort for homework, but otherwise this is built in:

> (sort (list 1 2 4 3) <)
>   (1 2 3 4)

Comment: how to include library in our program

Comment: Actually, sort is *not* built in to R5RS Scheme. (http://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-15.html#%_index_start). Bubble sort is also a bad choice for Scheme; it is very hard to write compared to insertion sort, for example.

Comment: Hi Nathan - thanks didn't know that was not in the standard. Just started to learn scheme.

Comment: Bubble sort is a bad choice for anything.